# How to initiate AWS import export disk service

Tags: amazon-web-services, import

I'm looking to use [AWS import export disk](https://aws.amazon.com/snowball/disk/) to ship 2TB of data to AWS on an encrypted USB drive. For this volume of data it doesn't justify having a snowball device delivered to the office.

I'm in a supported region (Ireland), but on the AWS services I cannot see Import Export, only Snowball, which only has the option of having a Snowball device delivered.  How do I find this service to create the import job as described here: https://aws.amazon.com/snowball/disk/getting-started/ ?

Or is this service being withdrawn?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it isn't directly in the services, but is an S3 related tool that is accessed using a command line tool or the APIs.

This page explains: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSImportExport/latest/DG/ToolsforCreatingandManaging.html

> You can create an AWS Import/Export job using a command line tool ...
>
> To download the AWS Import/Export Web Service Tool
>
> - Click http://awsimportexport.s3.amazonaws.com/importexport-webservice-tool.zip.
> - Extract the zipped content to a directory on your computer.
>
> You also have the option of using the AWS Command Line Interface (AWS
> CLI) to create and manage your AWS Import/Export jobs. For information
> on installing and using the AWS CLI, see Getting Set Up with the AWS
> Command Line Interface in the AWS Command Line Interface User Guide.
>
> The AWS CLI reference for AWS Import/Export commands, along with
> helpful examples, can be found in the importexport commands section of
> the AWS CLI Reference.